# Woocommerce: Add product to cart via ajax only works when logged in

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to add products/variations to the woocommerce cart with ajax.
When the button is clicked, I make a post request like this:

```
$data = {
   action: 'add_to_cart',
   productid: product_id,
   variationid: variation_id
};
$.post( $ajaxurl, $data, function(response) {
   // feedback to user
});
```

in the functions.php I have the following

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_to_cart', 'add_to_cart' );
function add_to_cart(){

    global $woocommerce;

    $woocommerce->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies(true);
    if( isset($_POST['variationid']) ){
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $_POST['productid'], 1, $_POST['variationid'] );
    }
    else{
        $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $_POST['productid'] );
    }

    echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    wp_die();
}
```

This function returns the new amount of products in the cart, or when I echo the result of the `add_to_cart` I get the `cart_item_key`. So everything seems ok.

The thing I'm struggling with is, that it only works when I'm logged into WordPress, even though I get the same response of the `add_to_cart` function. When I visit the cart page while not logged in, I get an "empty cart" page.

Any ideas on this?

Additional info: as noted in the comments, when I'm logged in and have products in the cart and then log out, the cart is empty.

Comment: Where do you define the variable `$ajaxurl` ? Probably it's outputting some URL pointing to /wp-admin/ which of course would require authenticated user.

Comment: @SetSailMedia I have it coded in the template and get it via $('#ajaxurl').text(). The URL should be fine - I also get response from the function in the functions.php

Comment: @SetSailMedia it's: http://xxx.tld/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: All looks good. Are you testing this with products with/without variations and receiving same response?

Comment: Possible you may want to change this line: `if( isset($_POST['variationid']) ){` to: `if( isset($_POST['variationid']) && $_POST['variationid'] != '' ){` since that variable is always set, even if empty/null

Comment: @SetSailMedia yes, I tried both. Another thing is, when I'm logged in and have some products in the cart, then log out, the cart is empty. So it seems like the products in the cart are somehow linked to the account.

Comment: Hmmm, peculiar! Sorry I'm not much help. Do you have any Woo plugins or extensions also installed?

Comment: @SetSailMedia only "WooCommerce Weight Based Shipping". But I just tried to deactivate it and it didn't make any difference. Thanks for your effort anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I solved it!

the `$woocommerce->cart->maybe_set_cart_cookies(true);` has to come after `$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( id );`